# Why is Xdebug log empty?

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I am trying to setup xdebug so that I can debug php code on a remote server from PHP storm running on my local laptop.

It's not working but I thought a good place to start fixing the problem would be to look at the xdebug log.

Sadly, the xdebug log file remains empty.

I am trying to test xdebug by running a .php file where the first line is phpinfo()

The result of running the file gives me these lines relating to xdebug:

```
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 10.1.12.136 => 10.1.12.136
xdebug.remote_log => /home/mfowler/xdebug.log => /home/mfowler/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => xdebug_test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => xdebug_test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => xdebug_test.php
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => xdebug_test.php
```

However /home/mfowler/xdebug.log has nothing in it.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying your local file is empty, or your remote file is empty? You may want to check that the remote receiver you are using is actually working/being connected to. For local, make sure profiler_enable is on.

Comment: Maybe because xdebug see no reason to engage (e.g no special xdebug cookie or GET/POST parameter)? Set `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` or put `xdebug_break();` in that PHP file and try again. Also, make sure that log file location is writeable by anyone.

Comment: xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 did the trick for me, log is now being filled, thank you!

Comment: successfully connected to debugclient, via localhost (on the remote server). now just have to figure out how to get xdebug to connect remotely to my laptop...

Comment: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` did the trick for me as well

Comment: My xdebug also just stopped working one day. I did not have ```xdebug.remote_autostart = 1``` in my php.ini and adding it fixed my issue. I did have to restart apache....

Comment: In my case the directory permissions were 755, needed to give it 775.

Answer (score 1):

Check proper log configuration, I prefer maximum log level:

**For Xdebug 2**

```
# always start
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
# log settings
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_log_level=7
```

**For Xdebug 3**

```
# always start
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
# log settings
xdebug.log="/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.log_level=7
```

Please be sure that log file created and accessed, i.e:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/xdebug
touch /tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
chmod 777 /tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
```

To check if remote port listening - use telnet:

```
telnet 10.1.12.136 9000
```

Comment: check php_info()  that Xdebug is there and settings are the same

Comment: Yes, problem was settings where ignored. I had xdebug setting defined, but commented the line in docker compose - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

which should have written those settings. I do not like how it works, it should still log that there is no logging turned on, check settings so you could know what to do. Now it does no work but does not give errors.